# format php timestamp to mysql format

Tags: php

I am building an attendance module, and I need to store the timestamp of users logging in and logging out. Also the admin has a feature to be able to generate attendance reports between date ranges, so I need to store the timestamps in mysql timestamp format so that I can later query the table for a given date range.

My current code is like this

```
<?php
$timestamp = time();

echo $timestamp;



$date = date("l jS of F Y h:i:s A",$timestamp);

echo $date;
?>
```

This gives the output `Sunday 5th of October 2008 02:08:15 PM`
I searched a lot but couldn't find the correct way to format like this `2008-10-05 14:08:15`

Comment: You searched a lot? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver my search query was, format timestamp to mysql and the results I got didn't include php.net manual for date function. I know how to manipulate the date function into different formats. I have not worked with the `time()` function didn't know it would be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Think this is what you need:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Output:

```
2015-02-12 20:13:27
```